# python socket receive only last line

Tags: python-3.x

I am using below provided code to retrive some data with the socket. Issue with this code, it prints all the results till it breaks eventhough I only care for the received line right before it breaks, the second last in other words. So, I need some help to understand how that can be achieved.

```
import socket
import time

socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("192.168.50.102", 2102))


curIndex = "0"
while True:
    sending_data = 'get,trx,'+curIndex
    #print sending_data
    client.send(sending_data)
    data = client.recv(128)
    print data.encode('UTF-8')
    if data == "trx,notfound": break

    spdata = data.split(",")
    #print spdata[2] + 'kg' #Prints weight + kg

    if len(spdata) >= 3:
        curIndex = spdata[1]

    time.sleep(0.5)
client.close()
```

Actual output

```
trx,2,1.250,0.000,19-07-11 14:08:01
trx,3,0.500,0.000,19-07-11 14:19:24
trx,4,0.500,0.000,19-07-11 15:04:37
trx,5,0.250,0.000,19-07-11 15:05:31
trx,6,0.177,0.000,19-07-11 21:06:59
trx,7,0.108,0.000,19-07-12 14:54:00
trx,8,0.106,0.000,19-07-16 17:51:06
trx,9,0.106,0.000,19-07-16 17:54:24
trx,10,0.106,0.000,19-07-18 14:31:49
trx,11,0.171,0.000,19-07-18 14:51:31
trx,notfound
```

Desired output
`trx,11,0.171,0.000,19-07-18 14:51:31`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not print it : save it.
Replace :

```
print data.encode('UTF-8')
if data == "trx,notfound": break
```

By

```
if data == "trx,notfound": break
last_data = data.encode('UTF-8')
```

Then, at the end (like after `client.close()`) you can `print last_data`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
data_b = client.recv(1024)
while data_b:
    data_b = client_socket.recv(1024)
    data += data_b
```

instead of

```
data = client.recv(128)
```

example

```
import socket

def main(): 
    port = 'Your port'
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(("", int(port)))
    server_socket.listen(5)

    print('TCPServer Waiting for client on port '+port+'\n')
    while True:
        print('Listening ...', end='\r')
        client, address = server_socket.accept()

        print("Connection from ", address[0])
        data = None

        while True:
            data_b = client.recv(1024)
            data = data_b
            if data_b:
                print("Receiving a file...")
                while data_b:
                    data_b = client_socket.recv(1024)
                    data += data_b
                else:
                    break

        print(data.decode())

client.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```